# Congruence of first grade

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the congruence $8x\equiv 10\pmod 6.$

Hello. My question is about of the solution. Because my Professor me indicated the solution:

$8x\equiv 10\pmod 6\iff 8x-6k=10$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}.$ Can use the Euclides algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: One, replace "any" with "some" please, as stated what you have written is plain wrong. Two, sure, do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry. Ok, I 've managed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the modulus is so small, just try $0,1,2,3,4,5$ mod 6 for $x$ and see that only $2$ and $5$ make $8x \equiv 10$ mod $6.$